# Need help understanding unexpected output from Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

```
package com.j;

public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Puzzel.class.getName().replaceAll(".", "/")
            + ".class");

    System.out.println(Program.class.getName());

}
```

}

in the above program i was expecting a output com/j/Program.class

But it is coming //////.class its y?

Comment: Regex is used for `replaceAll()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the replacement, `.` is treated as a regular expression, where `.` means "any character" and here is replaced with `/` , so the output becomes

```
////////////.class
```

For the expected answer, change the expression to escape the `.`:

```
Name.class.getName().replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ".class");
```

Then the output will be what you expected:

```
com/j/Puzzel.class
```

Comment: You should use `replace()` instead.

Comment: @arshajii yeah you are right by using replace() we can do replace . to / .but this output coming because . is a special char when it comes to regex.

Answer (score 2):

Because `.` is a special char when it comes to regex. You should escape it with backslash.

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll() takes a regular expression for the matcher.  Your code says to replace every character (`.`) with a `/`.  you need `replaceAll("\\.")`  or maybe `replaceAll("\\\\.")`.  I can never remember how many escapes to use offhand.